# Combing tidyverse + survey [R]: How to use svyglm in Nest-Map-Unnest-Chain?

Tags: r, tidyverse, nested-loops, glm

I am currently struggling to run weighted regression models on multiple variables in R.

When using (non-weighted) glm, I was successful by running the following:

```
mtcars_1 <- mtcars %>%
  nest(-gear)%>%
  mutate(model_0      = map(data, ~ glm(vs ~ drat, family = "binomial", data = .)))%>%
  mutate(model_0_tidy = map(model_0, tidy))%>%
  select(gear, model_0_tidy)%>%
  ungroup()%>%
  unnest(model_0_tidy)
```

That is I receive the following:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 6
   gear term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
  <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1     4 (Intercept)  -15.3       22.6     -0.677   0.499
2     4 drat           4.26       5.76     0.740   0.459
3     3 (Intercept)   -3.91       7.39    -0.529   0.597
4     3 drat           0.801      2.32     0.345   0.730
5     5 (Intercept)    5.20      14.4      0.362   0.718
6     5 drat          -1.71       3.77    -0.453   0.651
```

However, when I would like to weight my observations and thus use **svyglm** from the survey-package, nesting does not work.

This was my approach:

```
design_0 <- svydesign(ids=~0, data = mtcars, weights = mtaars$wt)

mtcars_2 <- mtcars%>%
  nest(-gear)%>%
  mutate(model_1 = map(data, ~ svyglm(vs ~ drat, family = quasibinomial(logit), design = design_0, data = .)))%>%
  mutate(model_1_tidy = map(model_1, tidy))%>%
  select(gear, model_1_tidy)%>%
  ungroup()%>%
  unnest(model_1_tidy)

# If suggested that wt serves as frequency weight

# Outcome

   gear term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
  <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1     4 (Intercept)    -8.12      3.88     -2.09  0.0451
2     4 drat            2.12      1.07      1.99  0.0554
3     3 (Intercept)    -8.12      3.88     -2.09  0.0451
4     3 drat            2.12      1.07      1.99  0.0554
5     5 (Intercept)    -8.12      3.88     -2.09  0.0451
6     5 drat            2.12      1.07      1.99  0.0554
```

Estimates for each type of gear (that is 3,4,5) turns out to be the same.

It appears as if nesting was essentially ignored here.

**Are there any solutions for combining svyglm with nest-map-unnest? Or will I have to look for other, less comfortable ways?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to do it this way

```
  mtcars%>%
  nest(-gear) %>% 
  mutate(design = map(data, ~ svydesign(ids=~0, data = .x, weights = ~ wt)),
         model = map(.x = design,
                     .f = ~ svyglm(vs ~ drat,
                                   family = quasibinomial(logit),
                                   design = .x))) %>% 
  mutate(model_tidy = map(model, tidy)) %>% 
  select(gear, model_tidy)%>%
  ungroup()%>%
  unnest(model_tidy)
```